# Dynamic create table in javascript not showing column properly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a dynamic table using a text box onchange function. It shows all rows and columns, but the columns aren't being displayed properly. How can I fix it?

```js
function toggleTable(val) {
  var root = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  table.className = "mytable";
  var tblB = document.createElement('tbody');
  table.appendChild(tblB);

  var rowcnt = val;

  headerList = ["One", "Two", "Three"];

  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  // Header row
  for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    var th = document.createElement('th'); //column
    var text = document.createTextNode(headerList[j]); //cell
    th.appendChild(text);
    tr.appendChild(th);
  }
  tblB.appendChild(tr);
  for (var i = 0; i < rowcnt; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tblB.appendChild(tr);
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    //tr.appendChild(td);  
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      var element = document.createElement("input");
      element.type = "text";
      element.name = "sch" + i;
      if (i >= 0 && j == 0) {
        element.value = "Sch" + i;
      }
      tr.appendChild(element);
    }
  }
  root.appendChild(table);
} <
/script>
```

```css
<style>.mytable {
  width: 200px;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #517994;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.mytable td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>hellotest table </title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h1>table test </h1>
  </center>

  <div id="mydiv"></div> <input type="text" name="sch" value="0" onChange="toggleTable(this.value)">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the `input` to a `td` and then append the `td` to the `tr`. At the moment, you're appending the `input` directly to the `tr`, which doesn't work.

(This is one reason why precise variable names are useful - a variable named `element` is less understandable than a variable named `input`, for example)

```
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  input.name = "sch" + i;
  const td = document.createElement('td');
  td.appendChild(input);
  if (i >= 0 && j == 0) {
    input.value = "Sch" + i;
  }
  tr.appendChild(td);
```

```js
function toggleTable(val) {
  var root = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  table.className = "mytable";
  var tblB = document.createElement('tbody');
  table.appendChild(tblB);

  var rowcnt = val;

  headerList = ["One", "Two", "Three"];

  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  // Header row
  for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    var th = document.createElement('th'); //column
    var text = document.createTextNode(headerList[j]); //cell
    th.appendChild(text);
    tr.appendChild(th);
  }
  tblB.appendChild(tr);
  for (var i = 0; i < rowcnt; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tblB.appendChild(tr);
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    //tr.appendChild(td);  
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      input.type = "text";
      input.name = "sch" + i;
      const td = document.createElement('td');
      td.appendChild(input);
      if (i >= 0 && j == 0) {
        input.value = "Sch" + i;
      }
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  }
  root.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
.mytable {
  width: 200px;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #517994;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.mytable td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>table test </h1>
</center>

<div id="mydiv"></div> <input type="text" name="sch" value="0" onChange="toggleTable(this.value)">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and the explanation.

Comment: Hi, the table is created perfect dynamically. But when i use second time text box to create a table. the first one also appears. I need to keep the latest one to display. Not the previous ones. Do you have an idea? Or is it a new question to post? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: If you need to only have one table from `toggleTable` displayed at any point, have `table` be a *persistent* variable, not a variable scoped only to the inside of `toggleTable`. If `table` exists when `toggleTable` is run, remove it from the document (or clear its `textContent` if you want to re-use it)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I just finished it! Had two variables for textbox (old and newvalue). having one more onchange event for the textbox to see if the value is same or not. if the value is not same then elementbyid.mydiv.innerhtml = " "; it works perfect :-)